# angular view not updating from shared service

Tags: caching, angularjs, service, modal-dialog

i need a little bit of help structuring my angular app.

I have two controllers, 'OfferListCntrl' (displays a list of offers) and 'OfferDetailsCntrl' (displays a single offer via id) as well as a service/model called 'Offers'. They connect to two web services respectively via the Offers service, GetOffers (returns array of offers) and GetOffer (returns single offer) and i am trying to Avoid calling GetOffer(id) if GetOffers has already been called (saves a service call)

```
MyApp.factory('Offers', function($http,Config) {
var data=[];
var Offers = {
    get: function () {
        var promise = $http.get(Config.API_END_POINT + "GetOffers?appID=12",{cache:"true"})
        .then(function (response){
            data = response.data;
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    },
    getOffer: function(id) {
        var local = _.find(data.Offers, function(offer) { return offer.OfferID == id });                   
        if(local){
            console.log("local copy found:" + local.OfferID);
            console.log(local.Description);
            console.log(local);
            return local;
        }
        else {
            var promise = $http.get(Config.API_END_POINT + "GetOffer?appID=12&OfferID=" + id,{cache:"true"})
            .then(function (response){
                console.log("no local, calling ws");
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }

    }
};  
return Offers;
});



function OfferDetailCtrl($scope,$http,Offers) {  
    Offers.get().then(function (asyncData){
        $scope.offers = asyncData.Offers;
    });
}]);


function OfferDetailCtrl($scope,$routeParams,$http,$location,Offers) { 
    $scope.offerId = $routeParams.offerId;
    Offers.getOffer($scope.offerId).then(function (asyncData){
        $scope.offer = asyncData;
    });
}
```

1 questions.

1. The trouble is when Offers.getOffer(id) is called: it seems to detect wether it has local data or not as expected, if there is no local data it calls the webservice and everything is fine, but if there is existing data, it tries to return it to the OfferDetailCtrl and then errors. I can console.log the contents of it just before returning and it all seems to be intact so im confused why the controller will accept a promise but not the actual object.

> Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'Offers.getOffer($scope.offerId).then(function (asyncData){
>         $scope.offer = asyncData;
>         console.log($scope.offer);
>       })') OfferDetailCtrl@http://staging.scanzap.com.au/assets/js/offers/OfferDetailController.js:17

if there is a better way i could be doing this id love to hear it :) thank you for your help

Comment: The answer is a service... I should buy the domain theanswerisaservice.com it's so often the answer on SO questions for AngularJS.  If you need to maintain persistent state of some objects across the life of the application (for the sake of sharing data and not creating extra requests) a service is the solution. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=26m40s < I suggest watching the whole talk many times when you have time.

Comment: The other option if a service doesn't make sense for communication between your controllers is using events ($on, $broadcast, $emit) to communicate between child/parent scoped controllers.

Comment: thanks for the reply, and ill check out the link. However i thought thats what i was already doing with 'Offers', and am injecting it into both controllers as you can see in the code above. Is Offers as i have defined it above (using the factory method) not a service?

Comment: Ah right I see, you are doing what I was saying I'll take a few minutes here and see if I can figure out where you're going wrong... I think it looks like your getOffer(id) function returns the value or optionally is returning a promise.  Basically since it's potentially asynchronous you should just always be returning a promise (but one you make in the function) then regardless of what happens in the function (finds local or goes remote) you should resolve the promise with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this instead be sure to inject $q as well.

```
getOffer: function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var local = _.find(data.Offers, function(offer) { return offer.OfferID == id });                   
        if(local){
            console.log("local copy found:" + local.OfferID);
            console.log(local.Description);
            console.log(local);
            deferred.resolve(local;)
        }
        else {
            var promise = $http.get(Config.API_END_POINT + "GetOffer?appID=12&OfferID=" + id,{cache:"true"})
            .then(function (response){
                console.log("no local, calling ws");
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;

    }
```

Comment: thanks for this, i was thinking it was something along these lines. Unfortunately i am still getting an error

(chrome:)

    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'
    at new OfferDetailCtrl 

(safari:)
    Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Offers.getOffer($scope.offerId).then(function (asyncData){
     //console.log("async data",asyncData);
     $scope.offer = asyncData;
    })')

Comment: this is how its being called...wether i implement your solution above or leave it as is i get that same error

`code`
    Offers.getOffer($scope.offerId).then(function (asyncData){
     $scope.offer = asyncData;
    });
`code`

Comment: ah, had to return myPromise.promise to get it to work, edited to reflect change, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: oops sorry I was trying to do that from memory and then went off gaming for a bit, glad you got it sorted.  Edited my answer... is there still any problem then?